# How get metadata of video in Blackberry 10 Cascade?

Tags: metadata, cascade, blackberry-10

I have C++ Blackberry Cascade application. I'm trying to read metadata of video file using this code

```
onMetaDataChanged: {
                    console.log("player onMetaDataChanged");
                    console.log("--------------------------------bit_rate=" + myPlayer.metaData.bit_rate);
                    console.log("-----------------------------------genre=" + myPlayer.metaData.genre);
                    console.log("-----------------------------sample_rate=" + myPlayer.metaData.sample_rate);
                    console.log("-----------------------------------title=" + myPlayer.metaData.title);  }
```

But this only works after the video file is played. Is there any way to get metadata of video file, without playing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call prepare slot. It will acquire resources necessary for playback without playing the track and emit MetaDataChanged signal.

> myPlayer.prepare()